# Replacing display-buffer-reuse-frames

Tags: buffers, frames

`display-buffer-reuse-frames` tells Emacs to re-use frames for displaying buffers.   However, as of 24.3 this variable is obsolete (emphasis mine):

> display-buffer-reuse-frames is a variable defined in `window.el`. 
>   Its value is t 
>   Original value was nil
>
> **This variable is obsolete since 24.3;
>     use a `reusable-frames` alist entry in `display-buffer-alist`.**
>
> Documentation: 
>   Non-nil means `display-buffer` should reuse frames.
>   If the buffer in question is already displayed in a frame, raise
>   that frame.

I understand that I am supposed to replace that variable with `display-buffer-alist`.  I'm familiar with the latter, and use it at many different places in my configuration, but nonetheless this docstring is a mystery to me.

What entry *exactly* do I need to add to `display-buffer-alist` to replicate this variable?  IOW, what entry do I need to add to `display-buffer-alist` to make Emacs reuse frames for **all buffers**, while still using the **default display actions**?

And please, dear Emacs developers, write less hand-wavy docstrings for obsolete options…

Comment: I suspect you cannot easily reproduce the original functionality of that obsoleted variable as the code suggests you can only enable it for specific `display-buffer-alist` items otherwise.

Comment: The doc (doc string and manual) for `display-buffer-alist` is a hard nut to crack, indeed. Consider filing a doc bug report, if you can say something concrete about a problem you encounter with it or you have a suggestion for improving it: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. FWIW, the doc, although still difficult to fathom, is better than it was at first.

Comment: @Drew Thanks, but as I said I'm familiar with `display-buffer-alist`, and I'm fine with its docstring.  My remark refers to the deprecation notice in the docstring of `display-buffer-reuse-frames`, which doesn't tell me the proper alternative instead.

Comment: Same comment applies in that case. A deprecation notice should make clear what to replace the deprecated construct with. Or if there is no replacement then it should say that. (IMHO.)

Comment: It may behoove the original poster to clarify the question by explaining why the (2) two examples in the documentation that utilize a `display-buffer-alist` entry of `(reusable-frames . 0)` do not address the issue at hand:  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Display-Action-Functions.html  In other words, explain *why* neither of these examples replicates the behaviour of `display-buffer-reuse-frames`, and shows how to reuse frames for all buffers, using the default display actions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`display-buffer` merges the various alists. Something like this should apply `reuse-frames` to all buffers.

```el
(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist
             '("." nil (reusable-frames . t)))
```

Alternatively use `display-buffer-overriding-action` or even `display-buffer-function` (as a wrapper), if feasible.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed.  I didn't know that `nil` was an acceptable value at this place.   Still, it's not perfect, though.  It must be the _last_ entry in `display-buffer-alist`, because it overrides any later entry with more specific actions.  Apparently, `display-buffer` merges alists, but not actions.

Comment: Yes, that's a problem.  Replacements of deperecations rarely provide the exact same functionality, I guess.

Comment: Looking at the code, it doesn't even merge alists, as I thought for some reason.  At least not the ones from `display-buffer-alist`, i.e. first match wins.