# How can I apply a frame register (saved via desktop.el) to the current frame instead of opening a new frame?

Tags: frames, desktop, registers

I am using `desktop.el` and I saved a few frame configurations in my registers. But when I jump to a saved register (`C-x r j`), Emacs opens a new frame instead of applying that setting to the current frame. If the register is saved in that session then it works as I expect, ie, the frame configuration is applied to the current frame. I want Emacs to always apply the frame register to the current frame. Is that possible?

The only variable I found that could be related is `desktop-restore-reuses-frames` but that is set to t (ie, reuse frame), and a search with customize-apropos for register and frames did not give me anything I thought could help.

[This question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14125/replacing-display-buffer-reuse-frames) and its answers could be a clue, but I couldn't figure out

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8567644/347646) could also give a clue. The function jump-to-register has a prefix argument that deletes the other frames, but I couldn't figure out how to make this work (I tried `C-u C-x r j R` and `C-u 0 C-x r j R` and `C-u 1 C-x r j R` but neither worked). I am not even sure this is what I want anyway.

I also looked into the library `frameset.el` and checked the `helm-apropos` for frameset but couldn't figure out how to do what I want. Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I cannot reproduce on Emacs 25 (official Cocoa version), maybe you can tell us how to reproduce from `emacs -Q`. (it seems you can use `M-x desktop-save`/`desktop-read` to store/restore Emacs session).

Comment: @xuchunyang,  I will try and get back to you (not at home at the moment). In the meantime, could you try closing the frame you used to set the register, open a new one, then restart emacs and see if jumping to that register opens a new frame? Not sure if it has anything to do with it, just a very uneducated guess

Comment: I am still unable to reproduce, while I am not quite sure your expectation and I have a feeling that this is nothing to do with `desktop.el` and Emacs's restore frame behavior is just not like what you expect.